# Proper format for user input of time for timespan conversion VB

Tags: vb.net, variables, datetime, datetimepicker, timespan

I am currently using combo boxes for the user to input specified times to be stored into DateTime variables. These DateTime variables will then be added or subtracted respectively to obtain a TimeSpan variable. 
The combo box text if formatted like this:

```
12:00:00 AM
01:00:00 AM
02:00:00 AM
03:00:00 AM
'ect...
```

This is what my code looks like when inputting the combo box info into a DateTime Variable:

```
parentsStart = CDate(ComboBox2.SelectedText)
parentsEnd = CDate(ComboBox3.SelectedText)
```

This is obviously not working code. What would be the proper formatting of the combo box or conversion method to get the user input into the DateTime variable? Also would is there a better way for users to input a time value via the DateTimePicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the formatting of the times.  You just need to use `DateTime.Parse()` when you convert a `String` to a `DateTime` object.

Pardon the code sample, as I'm using https://dotnetfiddle.net to simulate what you're asking, so I used a `List` instead of `ComboBoxes`.  The areas that use my `List` objects you would replace with your `ComboBox` objects

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim myComboBox As New List(Of String)
        myComboBox.Add("12:00:00 AM")
        myComboBox.Add("1:00:00 AM")
        myComboBox.Add("2:00:00 AM")
        myComboBox.Add("3:00:00 AM")

        Dim myComboBox2 As New List(Of String)
        myComboBox2.Add("12:00:00 AM")
        myComboBox2.Add("1:00:00 AM")
        myComboBox2.Add("2:00:00 AM")
        myComboBox2.Add("3:00:00 AM")

        ' myComboBox(2) selects 2:00:00 AM and converts it to a DateTime object
        Dim myTimeStart As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(myComboBox(2))
        ' myComboBox2(3) selecs 3:00:00 AM and converts it to a DateTime object
        Dim myTimeEnd As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(myComboBox2(3))
        ' Subtracting myTimeStart from myTimeEnd results in a TimeSpan object
        Dim myTimeSpan = myTimeEnd.Subtract(myTimeStart)

        ' Output to console to show the results of the subtraction
        Console.WriteLine(myTimeSpan)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

> 01:00:00

Click https://dotnetfiddle.net/JOqFLB to see the sample and results

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229631(v=vs.100).aspx if you want to use a DateTimePicker instead of ComboBoxes.  The DateTimePicker can be setup to just display and configure times only.